# Laravel Orchid data binding in edit form

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code in Laravel orchid platform where I'm trying to update a field along with a relationship field of which multiple can be selected. On the add new form, I've added these attributes and they've been inserted into the tables but they're not shown as selected in the edit form. Can anyone help?

```php
//EditPackageScreen.php
<?php

namespace App\Orchid\Screens\Package;

use Orchid\Screen\Screen;
use Orchid\Screen\Actions\Button;
use Orchid\Screen\Layout;
use Orchid\Screen\Fields\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Orchid\Layouts\Package\PackageEditLayout;
use Orchid\Support\Facades\Toast;


use App\Package;

class EditPackageScreen extends Screen
{
    /**
     * Display header name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $name = 'Edit Package';

    /**
     * Display header description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $description = 'Edit package details in the form below.';

    /**
     * Query data.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function query(Package $package): array
    {
        $package->load(['tests']);
        dd($package);
        return [
            'package' => $package
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Button commands.
     *
     * @return Action[]
     */
    public function commandBar(): array
    {
        return [
            Button::make(__('Update'))
                ->icon('icon-check')
                ->confirm('Are you sure you want to update this package?')
                ->method('updatepackage'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Views.
     *
     * @return Layout[]
     */
    public function layout(): array
    {
        return [
            PackageEditLayout::class,
        ];
    }

    public function updatepackage(Request $request){
        $package = Package::find($request->package['id']);
        $package->name = $request->package['name'];

        $response = $package->update();

        if(!$response){
            Toast::error('Something went wrong! Could not update package.');
        }else{
            Toast::success('Package updated!');
        }

        return back();
    }
}
//PackageEditLayout.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Orchid\Layouts\Package;

use Orchid\Screen\Fields\Input;
use Orchid\Screen\Layouts\Rows;
use Orchid\Screen\Fields\Select;
use App\Test;

class PackageEditLayout extends Rows
{
    /**
     * Views.
     *
     * @throws \Throwable|\Orchid\Screen\Exceptions\TypeException
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            Input::make('package.name')
                ->type('text')
                ->max('100')
                ->required()
                ->title(__('Name'))
                ->placeholder(__('Package Name')),

            Select::make('package.tests.')
                    ->fromModel(Test::class, 'item_name')
                    ->multiple()
                    ->title(__('Tests'))
                    ->help('Specify tests under this package.'),

            Input::make('package.id')
                ->type('hidden'),
        ];
    }
}
//Package.php (Model)
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Orchid\Filters\Filterable;
use Orchid\Screen\AsSource;

class Package extends Model
{
    use AsSource, Filterable;

    protected $allowedSorts = [
        'name',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $allowedFilters = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function tests(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Test', 'test_packages', 'package_id', 'test_id');
    }
}

//Tables
//tests
"Field" "Type"  "Null"  "Key"   "Default"   "Extra"
"id"    "bigint(20) unsigned"   "NO"    "PRI"   \N  "auto_increment"
"item_number"   "varchar(255)"  "NO"    ""  \N  ""
"item_name" "varchar(255)"  "NO"    ""  \N  ""
"created_at"    "timestamp" "YES"   ""  \N  ""
"updated_at"    "timestamp" "YES"   ""  \N  ""

//packages
"Field" "Type"  "Null"  "Key"   "Default"   "Extra"
"id"    "bigint(20) unsigned"   "NO"    "PRI"   \N  "auto_increment"
"name"  "varchar(255)"  "NO"    ""  \N  ""
"created_at"    "timestamp" "YES"   ""  \N  ""
"updated_at"    "timestamp" "YES"   ""  \N  ""

//test_packages
"Field" "Type"  "Null"  "Key"   "Default"   "Extra"
"package_id"    "bigint(20) unsigned"   "NO"    "PRI"   \N  ""
"test_id"   "bigint(20) unsigned"   "NO"    "PRI"   \N  ""

//test_packages data
"package_id"    "test_id"
"12"    "1"
"12"    "4"
"12"    "7"
```

on package edit page, the selected tests does not show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, the issue was with the package itself. I've talked to the author and he has released a new version that fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You forget $target for get data from db..
add this into your PackageEditLayout

```
/**
    * Data source.
    *
    * @var string
    */
   public $target = 'package';
```